# Git Repository Permissions

Tags: git, github, coldfusion, repository

Currently working in a cold fusion environment and when pushing changes to the master branch of a repository, I'm receiving the following: "remote warning: unable to unlink Blah/Blah/Blah.db: Permission Denied".

I was informed that using "chmod -R u+w *" should fix the problem. Thoughts?

Comment: What is the actual filename (not blah.db)? It's not thumbs.db is it?

Comment: I'm guessing `g+w` :) failing that as Carl above says can you please give us some information on the file. Also are you on a Mac, Linux, BSD, etc..?